# Provide options for release variable settable at release time

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release definition that has a variable named "Sku" and I have marked this variable to be settable at release time. There is a restriction on the values possible for this variable as it can be only "Developer", "Basic" or "Standard". Is there a way I can provide these values as options that can be selected while creating the release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way I can provide these values as options that can be
>   selected while creating the release.

For this issue, I am afraid that this feature is not available in azure devops.

The value of varible with "settable at release time" option checked can be changed in the create release page but cannot be selected as options.

[image]